# Binary Search Tree: Display contents of the tree in a tree like fashion (recursive)

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I been at it for a while I can't figure it out. I am suppose to do a reverse order traversal (right-root-left) and pass the level of the root to the function ShowTree.
What exactly is the level of the root? Is it the height? If yes, this is the code for it:

```
public int getHeight()
{
    return getHeight(_root);
}
private int getHeight (BSTnode top)
{
    if (top == null)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int lftHeight = getHeight(top._left);
        int rhtHeight = getHeight(top._right);
        if (lftHeight > rhtHeight)
            return 1 + lftHeight;
        else 
            return 1 + rhtHeight;
    }
}
```

So I assign the value of getHeight to level and pass it to ShowTree. I am suppose to use the level of each node to compute how many spaces to insert in front of the data of each node.

```
public String ShowTree (int level) 
{
    return ShowTree(_root,level);
}
private String ShowTree(BSTnode myroot, int level)
{
    String result = "";
    if (myroot == null)
        return "";
    else
    {
        result += ShowTree (myroot._right, level + 1);
        result += myroot._data.toStringKey();
        result += ShowTree (myroot._left, level + 1);
        return result;
    }
}
```

However this diplays the tree like this:

c

b

a

When it should print like this:

```
      c
```

b

```
                 a
```

Comment: Two quick things:  

1.  Do you really need to have the 'level' variable?  You aren't using it in your code and the number of spaces (aka depth) is calculated by the implicite loop of the recursion.

2. Wouldn't it be more logical to pass the 'tree' into the public method instead of the level?

Answer (score 1):

In your `ShowTree(BSTnode, int)` method...

```
String result = ""; // no extra whitespace
```

Dont you mean...

```
String result = " "; //extra whitespace
```